# Cannot parse a correct URI

Tags: c#

I have this link: `www.axams-freizeitzentrum.com/ruifach-stadion.htm`

when I try to create an `Uri` using this code:

```
var link = new Uri("www.axams-freizeitzentrum.com/ruifach-stadion.htm");
```

this will return

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

what is wrong?

Comment: please take note that this address resolves as 
**http://www.axams-freizeitzentrum.com/system/web/notvalid.aspx?code=404** which means that the address given is not valid and to get a redirect to their home page

Comment: I'm pretty sure a URI must have a protocol such as `http://` or `ftp://` for example

Comment: @styx I cannot manage the uri, I need to store this in a database, if the link prompt to 404 is not a problem for me.. the main problem here is the correct link that Uri cannot parse for some weird reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check possible reasons here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(v=VS.100).aspx

You need to put the protocol prefix in front the address, i.e. in your case "http://"

```
var link = new Uri("http://www.axams-freizeitzentrum.com/ruifach-stadion.htm");
```

Comment: okay, there is a method that allow me to check if an Uri have such structure before call new uri?

Comment: `Uri.CheckSchemeName` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.checkschemename(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`Uri`s need a scheme name.

```
var link = new Uri("http://www.axams-freizeitzentrum.com/ruifach-stadion.htm");
```

Comment: how to check first if http is included in the string?

Comment: @Charanoglu `if(myUri.Contains(@"http"))`

Comment: @styx better use CheckSchemaName